# If $q\mid p-1$ then there is an integer $u$ such that $u$ has order $q$ modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

> If $q\mid p-1$ then there is an integer $u$ such that $u$ has order
> $q$ modulo $p$ - that is, such that $u^q\equiv 1$ mod $p$, and
>
> $u^r\not\equiv 1$ mod $p$ for $0<r<q$

$q\mid p-1$ means $p-1=qk$ for some integer $k$. I know that there exists some integer $x$ such that $x^{p-1}\equiv 1$ mod $p$. I thought this could be useful but I don't see how. Maybe I also need to use the fact that $q$ is prime number. How would I prove this?

Comment: Did you mean that $p$ is prime?  $\;(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times $ is cyclic

Comment: Yes, I think this was a dumb question, sorry. But is such $u$ unique? I think we have a unique $x$ and since $u=x^{\frac{p-1}{q}}$, $u$ may be unique, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh it may not be unique. For example in $Z/6$, both $2$ and $4$ have order 3...